# How were the phenomena relating to symmetric polynomials discovered?

Tags: mathematics, elementary-algebra

The "fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials" states that any symmetric polynomial can be expressed as a polynomial in the *elementary* symmetric polynomials. This, or at least variants on it or corollaries of it, was definitely known to Lagrange in the 18th century (probably many others) and possibly even to Newton.

I don't see anything "elementary" about the elementary symmetric polynomials - in the sense that I don't see anything about them that immedaitely suggests that *all* symmetric polynomials should be expressible by them. What do we know about how and when such an obscure yet powerful fact was discovered?

Comment: In his book *Enumerative Combinatorics*, Richard Stanley says that a good source of information for the early history of symmetric functions, including the fundamental theorem of symmetric functions, is an article by Karl Theodor Vahlen, "Rationale Funktionen der Wurzeln; symmetrische und Affektfunktionen," in *Encyklopädie der Mathematischen Wissenschaften*, Erster Band, Teubner, Leipzig, 1898-1904, pp. 449-479. Unfortunately I do not have access to this paper, and I don't read German, but maybe this reference will help you.